# Escape backslash in Python parameterized MySQL query

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am working on excel files and database storaging, precisely I am storaging excel data to MySQL database. At some point I am executing this query:

```
query_for_id = ''' SELECT id FROM attivita WHERE attivita = '{0}' '''.format(attivita)
```

And when I print the query result I get this:

' SELECT id FROM attivita WHERE attivita = \\'Manutenzione\\' '

When it tries to match 'attivita' with the right value, taken from the excel, I got errors because of the '\\'.

I tried changing the triple quotes from " " " to ' ' ', as well as using `connection.escape_string()`, but I didn't solve the problem. Can anyone help me figuring out the problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your case better to use arguments to execute

```
query_for_id = ''' SELECT id FROM attivita WHERE attivita = %(attivita)s '''
cursor.execute(query_for_id, { 'attivita': attivita })
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html